# roblox code issue: initialize with nil on cloning line

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local myhuman = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local myroot = script.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local head = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Head")
local grab = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Grab")
local grabanim = myhuman:LoadAnimation(grab)
grabanim.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action
local grabsound = head:WaitForChild("Hit")
local screamsound = head:WaitForChild("Groan")
    
local clone script.Parent:Clone()
    
    
function died()
wait(5)
clone.Parent = workspace
         
        
game:GetService("Debris"):AddItem(script.Parent,0.1)
end
```

That's my code, and I'm having trouble with the code. Parent line it says, "variable clone defined on line 12 is never initialized or assigned; initialize with "nil" to silence enter code here.`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the '=' chracter at `local clone script.Parent:Clone()`.
It has to say `local clone = script.Parent:Clone()`.